# Security Php Mysql Connection on different servers

Tags: php, mysql

Just a quick question about security when your database is not running on the same server as the web server. Is there by default any encryption in PHP on the communication between the two, and if not how big a problem is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does not deserve so many downvotes, I think.

By seperating the database from the web server you introduce a new attack vector, namely snooping traffic on the wire as it travels between the database and the web server.

This traffic is normally not encrypted, so you need to take action to make it so.

See for instance: http://www.madirish.net/214